# JTable columns doesnt resize probably when JFrame resize

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable

I got a JTable, which i applied AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN to. It auto resizes last column when i drag the columns left or right..

However, the JTable are attached to a JPanel with a BorderLayout manager. When i resize the JFrame, the JPanel resize, and since the JTable fills the JPanel, the JTable resizes too. But when i resize the JFrame, the AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN doesnt works, but instead it resizes all the columns.

I want it to **only** auto_resize the last column, when the JFrame changes size, instead of resize all columns.

code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class JTableResize extends JFrame {

    private JTable table;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JScrollPane pane;

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

    public JTableResize() {
        super("JTable - Resize Problem");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        table = new JTable(model);
        //panel.add(table);
        model.addColumn("Resize");
        model.addColumn("Problem");
        model.addColumn("........");
        model.addColumn("This should resize");

        pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(pane);

        //this is supposed to resize last column.. It works when you drag in the columns, but not when frame are resized
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        table.setShowVerticalLines(false);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
            model.addRow(new Object[] {i, i, i, i});
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTableResize jtr = new JTableResize();
        jtr.setSize(500, 500);
        jtr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jtr.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code..!!! it is working absolutely fine.

Comment: @Mac Try to run it, and resize the window to the right (make the window bigger). You should see, that all the Columns in the JTable are resizing. But i want it, to only resize the last column (right-most). So when i make the window bigger, only the last column will get bigger (extending). So the 3 first columns should resize, when window get bigger :)

Comment: Next time, please improve the original question rather than create a new one.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I will keep that in mind =). I deleted the old one though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the API documentation from the `doLayout()` method of `JTable`.

*Before the layout begins the method gets the resizingColumn of the tableHeader. When the method is called as a result of the resizing of an enclosing window, the resizingColumn is null. This means that resizing has taken place "outside" the JTable and the change - or "delta" - should be distributed to all of the columns regardless of this JTable's automatic resize mode.*

So this behaviour is not support by default.

Overriding the doLayout() method of the JTable and setting the "resizing column" to the last column seems to do the trick:

```
@Override
public void doLayout()
{
    if (tableHeader != null)
    {
        TableColumn resizingColumn = tableHeader.getResizingColumn();
        //  Viewport size changed. Increase last columns width

        if (resizingColumn == null)
        {
            TableColumnModel tcm = getColumnModel();
            int lastColumn = tcm.getColumnCount() - 1;
            tableHeader.setResizingColumn( tcm.getColumn( lastColumn ) ) ;
        }
    }

    super.doLayout();
}
```